# E053 Could not read config.cfg Resumeparser

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy

```
spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

from pyresparser import ResumeParser
data = ResumeParser('Resume.pdf').get_extracted_data()

OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from C:\Users\Kumaran\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\pyresparser\config.cfg

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-941548297df0> in <module>
      1 from pyresparser import ResumeParser
----> 2 data = ResumeParser('Resume.pdf').get_extracted_data()

~\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\pyresparser\resume_parser.py in __init__(self, resume, skills_file, custom_regex)
     19     ):
     20         nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
---> 21         custom_nlp = spacy.load(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
     22         self.__skills_file = skills_file
     23         self.__custom_regex = custom_regex

~\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, disable, exclude, config)
     45     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     46     """
---> 47     return util.load_model(name, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)
     48 
     49
```

Comment: I might try this with a different version of Python (3.6) via changing your anaconda environment to a new one with that version then running this again after installing the appropriate packages. Or, older versions of the ResumeParser package. Looks like someone is running into something similar in a GitHub issue: https://github.com/github/hub/issues/2711

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 27):

To solve the issues, install these versions:

```
pip install nltk

pip install spacy==2.3.5

pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1/en_core_web_sm-2.3.1.tar.gz

pip install pyresparser
```

Comment: your solution worked for me, THANK YOU Bro. Many other solutions throughout web did not worked. I was stuck with this 'spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')'  CONFIG.CFG issue for few hours. I was using Colab then.

Comment: It' not working for me

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me too, in Databricks.

Comment: Note that pyresparser is effectively incompatible with Python 3.10, because of the spacy dependency. This only worked for me when I changed the Python version to 3.9.

Comment: python -m spacy validate

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain what caused the E053 error: the installed models were not compatible with the installed spacy version. You can use `python -m spacy validate` to see your version and if you have any models for it, then install matching versions as in the above answer. Source: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/7453