# OSError: E053 Could not read config.cfg Spacy on colab

Tags: python, spacy

I want to use SpacyTextBlob in google Colab, when I use the [formal installation](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-textblob), I got the below error.

```
OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/config.cfg
```

what I do, first run this block:

```
import spacy
!pip install spacytextblob
```

then based on the output I restart the runtime. then run this code:

```
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe("spacytextblob")
```

but at the first line, I got the error.

if I don't install SpacyTextBlob the default version of  Spacy on Colab it's 2.2.4 but after installation the  Spacy version it's 3.2.1

there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66149878/e053-could-not-read-config-cfg-resumeparser/66168296#66168296) for the same error but I can't use it.

I guess the problem it's from the spacy version which changed after installing the Spacytextblob but how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide replicable errors? when I try the first 3 lines in Colab, i get  ```AttributeError: type object 'Language' has no attribute 'factory' ```

Comment: you need to restart the runtime to work. I change the order of the code in question. thank you @rikyeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by using this  [installation guide](https://pypi.org/project/spacytextblob/)

```
!pip install spacytextblob
!python -m textblob.download_corpora
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```